# Does Fidelity have equivalent ETFs of VFIAX and VDADX

Tags: etf, mutual-funds, vanguard, standard-and-poors-500, fidelity

I noticed that fidelity charges a fee for buying:

- Vanguard Index Admiral Fund (VFIAX)
- Vanguard Dividend Appreciation Fund (VDADX)

Does fidelity have equivalent funds of the above that I won't be charged a fee to buy?

Answer (score 1):

First a correction:

VFIAX isn't Vanguard Index Admiral Fund (VFIAX) it is

> [Vanguard 500 Index Fund Admiral Shares (VFIAX)](https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/profile/VFIAX)
>
> As the industry’s first index fund for individual investors, the 500
> Index Fund is a low-cost way to gain diversified exposure to the U.S.
> equity market. The fund offers exposure to 500 of the largest U.S.
> companies, which span many different industries and account for about
> three-fourths of the U.S. stock market’s value.

Yes Fidelity has multiple index funds, at least one of which has 500 in the name.

The other fund you will have to determine which fund matches the past performance of the Vanguard fund. Fidelity does have a page that will list all their [funds](https://www.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/fidelity-funds/overview) by various categories and sub categories, several do include dividend in the name of the fund.